# Package Ideas Base Theme Install Failed

Tags: ideas, unmanaged-package

I have an issue with package installation in my developer edition. I am working on Community. when I install this unmanaged application (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5GwhEAF) from sandbox to my dev edition, its getting failed.It going fine till the last of installation but at the end i'm getting the error.

[image]

Comment: Did you join the pilot? Is it available in your org?

Comment: i have tried it. but i am not able to log a case at https://help.salesforce.com. and i also look at this link https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h3S5AAI.

Comment: You must log your case from your production org. Developer orgs, sandboxes, etc, can't log cases.